# Python module requirement satisfied but import fails

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to import the `mysql` module in my script but I get an error that the module cannot be found. When I try to `pip install` it, it says that the requirement is already satisfied. I've included the screenshot with the error and also the output of `sys.path`. I'm not sure why Python cannot find this module (and some others as well), I tried looking up similar questions but none of the answers there helped in my case - can someone please help?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: If you run `pip install mysql` and then `python -c "import mysql"` in your shell instead of in Jupyter, do you get the same results?

Comment: Hi, I tried that in the shell. And it doesn't throw an error when I run `python -c "import mysql"`

Comment: Then clearly you are running different Python environments on the shell and in Jupyter. Things to look at: compare `sys.path` in Jupyter vs shell-python; on the shell, run `python -c "import mysql; print(mysql.__file__)"` and check if the path is in your Jupyter sys.path; in the shell, do `which jupyter` and `which python` both point to the same python installation? Hopefully one of these questions will lead you to a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the Jupyter notebook is using another Python version or environment than the shell.

Check the Python environment in `kernel.json` (to find this file run the command: `jupyter kernelspec list` at a command prompt, this will show you all available kernels with configuration paths).

Comment: Couldn't run it in the command prompt (says jupyter is not recognised as an internal or external command). Ran it in the anaconda command prompt and found the file `kernel.json`. The contents are `{
 "argv": [
  "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python.exe",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3",
 "language": "python"
}`

Comment: Then you probably have to install the module in the same Python env, try at a command prompt: `C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python.exe -m pip install mysql` or else use `conda install ...`.